# generating comma delimited string based on excel table 

Tags: .net, sql-server, excel, parsing, csv

I have to generate comma delimited string with key-value pair based on data in excel sheet.
Since picture is worth thousand words ...
[image: problem parsing excel]

Top row is column name and as visualized I want to turn row 1877 into following string

```
8:0,9:1,10:0,11:2 ...
```

so format would be `column_name:column_value,...`
Since I have lot of data to parse I'm curious if anybody can suggest the best approach to generate
string that will end up in ms sql database?

Thanks

Comment: Are the column names just the column numbers?

Comment: yes, they are just column numbers

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a one-time load you may just want to write a formula in excel and base your load off that.

```
=CONCATENATE(C$3,":",$C4,",",D$3,":",$D4,",",E$3,":",$E4,",",F$3,":",$F4)
```

The above can be copied down for all the rows.  It only covers the first 4 columns, but I think you get the point.

Again, I would only recommend this approach if this is a one-off load as it does require this manual step.  For something you need to repeat you should look at the capabilities of your ETL tools (i.e. SSIS)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I "solved" the problem of scrapping data from excel:
I named two ranges Rng_Col (Column headers) and Rng_Row (Column Row) and added a button.
[image]

than I've introduced following vba code:

```
Private Sub btnRun3_Click()
    'Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"
    Dim inserStatement As String
    insertStatement = "INSERT yourTableName(field1, field2, field3) VALUES(3, "
    Dim result, finalResult As String
    Dim offset As Integer
    offset = 1
    For Each r In Range("Rng_Rows3")
        For Each c In Range("Rng_Col3")
            result = result & "," & c.Value & ":" & r.offset(0, offset).Value
            offset = offset + 1
        Next c
        offset = 1
        finalResult = insertStatement & r.Value & ", N'" & Right(result, Len(result) - 1) & "') "
        Debug.Print finalResult
        result = ""
    Next r
End Sub
```

I've end up with sql insert statement; hope this might help somebody ...